# Como recuperar partes/valores específicas/os de uma string?

Tags: java, string

Tenho um `ArrayList` onde monto uma lista personalizada que é exibida em um `ListView`. O que preciso é passar o valor do item selecionado para outra tela.

Vejam abaixo o método que vai chamar a outra tela:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Object obj = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

    System.out.println(obj);

    Intent it = new Intent(this, ActHolerite.class);

    startActivityForResult(it, 0);
}
```

No método acima eu tenho o retorno abaixo (no `System.out`):

> I/System.out﹕ {tipcal=Cálculo Mensal, perref=Abril / 2015, codcal=405}

O que preciso passar para outra tela é apenas o **405** (referente ao `codcal=405`) pois ele é um campo chave de um select que vou usar nesta outra tela.

Como posso "*desmontar*" essa string e pegar apenas o numero **405**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como você precisa pegar apenas o número depois de `codcal` uma forma é usando expressões regulares.

Por exemplo, podemos usar este padrão: `codcal=(\d+)`. Ou seja, irá "casar" na string onde existir `codcal=` seguido por número, em qualquer quantidade.

Então, para recuperarmos, podemos buscar por este padrão na string e, caso exista, recuperar o grupo que temos interesse, o grupo número demarcado.

Um exemplo seria este:

```
final String string = "I/System.out: {tipcal=Cálculo Mensal, perref=Abril / 2015, codcal=405}";
final Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("codcal=(\\d+)");
final Matcher mat = pat.matcher(string);
if (mat.find()) {
    System.out.println(mat.group(1));
}
```

Comment: Muito bom... Muito obrigado Bruno!

Comment: Disponha @FábioAzevedo. Caso tenha sido útil, considere aceitar a resposta :)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o `substring()` para pegar apenas a parte do texto que lhe interessa.

Se o número que você quer pegar estiver sempre depois de `codcal=` e for a última parte da sua String, você pode fazer assim:

```
public class Str {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String texto = "tipcal=Cálculo Mensal, perref=Abril / 2015, codcal=405";
        int inicio = texto.indexOf("codcal=")+7;
        System.out.println(texto.substring(inicio));
    }
}
```

Usando o `substring()` passando apenas um valor você está definindo o iníco dela dentra da String `texto` e pegando tudo que vai até o seu final.

Caso por exemplo você tenha mais campos na sua String e estejam separadas por vírgula, pode fazer assim:

```
public class Str {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String texto = "tipcal=Cálculo Mensal, perref=Abril / 2015, codcal=405, mais_algo_aqui=1111";
        int inicio = texto.indexOf("codcal=")+7;
        int fim = texto.indexOf(",", inicio);
        System.out.println(texto.substring(inicio, fim));
    }
}
```

Nesse caso passamos dois parâmetros, o início e o fim da sua substring. Para o valor `fim` pegamos o índice da primeira vírgula depois do início da String, se você estivesse usando outro caractere para separar seus valores seria o caso de substituir na linha que inicializa a variável `fim`.

Para ambos os casos, saída:

> 405

Comment: Muito obrigado Math... deu certinho também! Abraço.