# Dividir String usando a vírgula como parâmetro

Tags: java, android, string

Estou tentando obter os valores de um ListView para enviá-los a uma outra tela ao clicar no item.

Portanto tenho o seguinte código:

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String sttr = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        System.out.println(sttr);

    }
```

O retorno da String é:

```
I/System.out﹕ {perref=May / 2015, tipcal=Cálculo Mensal, codcal=408}
```

Como posso separar em 3 strings esses 3 valores separados por vírgula?

Alguém já se deparou com a situação?

Tem alguma outra forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Isso aqui não lhe resolve? [Como recuperar partes/valores específicas/os de uma string?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/64577/3117)

Answer (score 4):

É como o @Onaiggac diz [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/66572/dividir-string-usando-a-v%C3%ADrgula-como-par%C3%A2metro/66577#66577).. Usando a função Split.

Caso precises de usar os valores que foram separados, podes é criar um array de strings para depois ter acesso a eles

```
String[] sol;
String sttr = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
sol = sttr.split(",");
```

Agora se quiseres chamar a 1ª String após a divisão:

...`sol[0];`

A 2ª:

...`sol[1];`

e assim sucessivamente

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o método [Split](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm) com expressão regular

```
  String sttr = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
  for (String retval: sttr.split(",")){
     System.out.println(retval);
  }
```

O método Split irá retornar um array de strings para cada vírgula encontrada.

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar esse formato também:

```
String[] separated = CurrentString.split(",");
separated[0];
separated[1];
```

Answer (score -1):

Além da resposta do @Onaiggac, é possível da seguinte forma (conforme @Math retornou em outra pergunta):

```
        int iniPerRef = retorno.toString().indexOf("perref=")+7;
        int fimPerRef = retorno.toString().indexOf(",", iniPerRef);
        System.out.println(retorno.toString().substring(iniPerRef, fimPerRef));

        int iniTipCal = retorno.toString().indexOf("tipcal=")+7;
        int fimTipCal = retorno.toString().indexOf(",", iniTipCal);
        System.out.println(retorno.toString().substring(iniTipCal, fimTipCal));

        int iniCodCal = retorno.toString().indexOf("codcal=")+7;
        int fimCodCal = retorno.toString().indexOf("}", iniCodCal);
        System.out.println(retorno.toString().substring(iniCodCal, fimCodCal));
```