# Como ler uma string pré-formatada?

Tags: java, string

Tenho um arquivo com String em um determinado formato, gostaria de capturar dessa string algumas informações. Exemplo:

```
0:13:13 - ID:( usuário ) / Name:( nome ) / IP ( 177.22.XX.X ) Memory Function Code Error ( 1 )( 267 354 24 )( 12 15 5 )
```

Gostaria de pegar os dados como hora, id, nome, ip e a frase de descrição.

Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35400/como-obter-um-trecho-de-uma-string/35401#35401  tem uma resposta do @bigown

Comment: Sim, dê uma olhada nas respostas desta pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/64577