# Ler um trecho de uma String

Tags: java, string

Como vocês viram minha pergunta acima, eu quero pegar apenas uma parte que me interessa de uma String, por exemplo, eu tenho uma String `preco` cujo texto é `R$ 20,00`, como faço para pegar somente o número ? Outra dúvida é que se eu tentar somar um número separado com vírgula e não por ponto ele dá erro ?

Dúvida de muitos principiantes em Java ...

Comment: Veja esses links, eles respondem as duas dúvidas: [Como recuperar partes/valores específicas/os de uma string?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/64577/28595) e [Converter String para Float com virgula em Java](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115362/28595)

Comment: Dica, use a pesquisa, quase todas as dúvidas mais básicas tem perguntas respondidas aqui no site mesmo. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    public static void main(String []args) throws ParseException {
       String preco = "R$ 20,00";
       //função substring retorna uma nova string apartir do índice passado para ela.
       //a função trim retira espaços que podem porventura ficar na nova String
       String valor = preco.substring(2).trim(); //20,00

       //NumberFormat do Locale default
       NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("pt", "BR"));
       //converte um número com vírgulas a partir de uma String para float
       float number = nf.parse(valor).floatValue(); //20.0

       //quando for fazer a soma faça um cast que não ocasionará erro se não colocar o ponto
       float soma = (float) (number + 4.4); //24.4
       float soma1 = (float) (number + 4); //24.0
    }
```

Referências

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)
- [Converter String para Float com virgula em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/115362/converter-string-para-float-com-virgula-em-java)

Comment: Evite links como resposta, ao menos que eles complemente uma resposta válida.

Comment: Seguindo as dicas fiz modificações na resposta.

Answer (score -1):

Referente a pegar uma parte de uma String, você pode usar uma Substring para isso. Vamos trocar também a virgula por ponto para trabalhar em float e realizar o calculo desejado.

## ficaria desta forma:

```
 public static void main(String []args){
    String preco= "R$20,00";
    int um;
    int dois;

    //pega numeros a esquerda da virgula. . .
    um = preco.indexOf("$");
    dois = preco.lastIndexOf(",");
    String precoX = preco.substring(um + 1, dois);
    System.out.println("precoFinal" + precoX.toString());

    //Numeros a direita da Virgula. . .
    um = preco.indexOf(",");
    dois = preco.lastIndexOf(preco.charAt(preco.length() - 1));
    String precoY = preco.substring(um + 1, dois + 1);
    System.out.println("precoFinal" + precoY.toString());

    //Preco pronto para ser convertido. . .
    String precoFinal = OrganizaNumero(precoX, precoY, ".");//até esta etapa, coloquei o ponto no lugar da virgula e tirei o R$ da string. . .


    //converte precoFinal pra float. . .
    float f = Float.parseFloat(precoFinal.toString());

    //soma com outro float. . .
    f = f + 30.50f;

    //transforma novamente em String. . .
    String valorSomado = Float.toString(getFloat(f));
    System.out.println("string" + valorSomado.toString());


 }

 public static float getFloat(float x){return x;}
 public static String organizaNumero(String x, String y, String z){return "" + x.toString() + z.toString() + y.toString();}
```

Comment: Isso não responde realmente as duas dúvidas da pergunta.

Comment: Você pegou o número mas ele continua em String, como faria para somar com outro número?

Comment: Editei a resposta. Agora ele mostra como como converte de float para String e vice versa para reralizar os cálculos e voltar para String. Converti a virgula do valor para ponto também, para poder ser usado nos calculos. Se quiser transformar o ponto em virgula novamente no resultado. pode fazer da mesma forma que fiz no inicio do código (pega parte da esquerda e da direita do ponto e  usa no método organizaNumero)